# SAM app deploy gives preflight error but if I create OPTIONS method in aws apigateway console my preflight passes

Tags: cors, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, sam

I'm using SAM to create an API in cloudformation.

**QUESTION:**
Where in my SAM application template do I add the 'X-Requested-With' header? 
How can I edit my code so that the preflight will succeed without me having to go into the AWS console?

**PROBLEM:**
I'm working with my preflight request and when I deploy my SAM application I get 403 FORBIDDEN in postman and when I go to the AWS console the header 'X-Requested-With' is not present.

If I try to just add the 'X-Requested-With' header afterward in the console it still gives the error, **BUT if I delete the OPTIONS method in the console and create the OPTIONS method from scratch** according to  (https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html) **it works and I get a 200 OK in postman**.
[image]

[image]

**CODE:**

template.yaml

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Requested-With,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"

Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: true

 MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: mypath/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        KrySeisoen:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /mypath
            Method: get
      Policies:
        - ...
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - ...
        SubnetIds:
          - ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was barking up the wrong tree.

The problem that I was having was not with the 'X-Requested-With' header, but rather the fact that my SAM application was setting the ApiKeyRequired to true for all the methods.

All I had to do was to set the ApiKeyRequired to false for all the options methods.

Here is a link to another question with the solution to my problem.
[Preflight response 403 forbidden. How can I allow options method without x-api-key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60899237/preflight-response-403-forbidden-how-can-i-allow-options-method-without-x-api-k)