# Preflight response 403 forbidden. How can I allow options method without x-api-key?

Tags: cors, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, preflight, sam

I'm using SAM to create my API in cloudformation.

I'm getting a 403 FORBIDDEN on my options method (thus also my preflight for my get method).

How can I allow my options method to reply with 200 OK without my x-api-key?

I've tried so many stackoverflow answers but none fit my SAM template format. I've tried all the different combinations of my AllowHeaders. I've ommited the x-api-key - still the same 403 FORBIDDEN.

If I send my x-api-key in postman with my request I get a 200 OK, but in my reactjs application it still gives the same error as below that my preflight does not pass.

Console log response to the get method
[image]

Postman response to the options method (preflight testing)
[image]

Cloudwatch error
[image]

template.yaml

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 10
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,x-api-key,Authorization,Origin,Host,X-Requested-With,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers'"
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"

Resources:
  BSApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Auth:
        ApiKeyRequired: true
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false

  GrondvogFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: grondvog/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy: {
          'FunctionName': !Ref RDBQueryFunction
        }
      Environment:
        Variables:
          "RDBQueryFunctionName": !Ref RDBQueryFunction
      Events:
        KryGrondvog:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BSApi
            Path: /grondvog
            Method: get
        OptionsGrondvog:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BSApi
            Path: /grondvog
            Method: options
```

Lambda function

```
if (event.httpMethod == 'OPTIONS') {
        rekords = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,X-Amz-Security-Token,x-api-key,Authorization,Origin,Host,X-Requested-With,Accept,Access-Control-Allow-Methods,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT",
                "X-Requested-With": "*"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ statusText: "OK" })
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution.

I missed the part where I should tell my SAM application that for the options method I must specify that I don't want the api key. I just added the following to each options method:

```
Auth:
  ApiKeyRequired: false
```

```
GrondvogFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: grondvog/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Policies:
        - LambdaInvokePolicy: {
          'FunctionName': !Ref RDBQueryFunction
        }
      Environment:
        Variables:
          "RDBQueryFunctionName": !Ref RDBQueryFunction
      Events:
        KryGrondvog:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BSApi
            Path: /grondvog
            Method: get
        OptionsGrondvog:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref BSApi
            Path: /grondvog
            Method: options
            Auth:
              ApiKeyRequired: false
```

Comment: Hey, I ran in to the same issue, my OPTIONS requests are requiring the API Key. But I am not declaring my options explicitly and instead I'm just letting the AWS SAM add it in, because in my case I'm not calling a function when the user makes an OPTIONS request., do you know how I can allow the API Key not to be required

Comment: @SGolds did you find the solution? I have the same case. I do not specify OPTIONS methods in my sam template, however browser makes these requests and the response is an error: x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException

Comment: Hi, yes I actually removed the auth from the api resource and then added auth directly on my GET paths that required the key. (Your setup may be different but I am adding my api resources by adding api events to my lambda functions, so I just added auth to those sections instead of the api)

Comment: Can u  share the screenshot of the api gateway console (hiding the sensitive part)

Comment: @NitinSingh To clarify, which part are you interested in so that I can share a screenshot of the relevant part.

Comment: Hi @PouncingPoodle we managed to recreate the whole structure with OPTIONS without ApiKey and ANY as required. Thanks